# show/hide v-tab depend to the related v-checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vuejs2, tabs, vuetify.js

Hello i'm trying to make a global dynamic component with some extra features.
my question is :How can i show/hide v-tab depend on the v-checkbox value? this is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs v-model="activeTab">
      <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="`${index}-tab`" v-if="checked">
        {{ item.name }}
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab-item v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="`${index}-tab`">
        <v-card flat>
          {{ item.name }}
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
      <v-menu
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-width="200"
        offset-x
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
              <v-icon>mdi-eye</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedTabs" multiple>
              <template v-for="(item, index) in tabs">
                <v-list-item :key="`${index}-tab`">
                  <v-list-item-action class="ma-0">
                    <v-checkbox
                      :key="`${index}-tab`"
                      @click="hidecont(item)"
                    ></v-checkbox>
                  </v-list-item-action>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </template>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
    </v-tabs>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: 0,
      selectedTabs: [],
      menu: false,
      checked: false,
      tabs: [
        {
          name: "tab1"
        },
        {
          name: "tab2"
        },
        {
          name: "tab3"
        }
      ]
    };
  },

  methods: {
    hidecont(item) {
      console.log("item");
      // i know this will not work in my case
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How it should be : for example when the checkbox(tab1) checked/unchecked => the v-tab(tab1) should be hidden/visible according to the related checkbox...
i tried several ways but it doesn't matter in which checkbox i click i got all the v-tabs hidden or visible, the problem hier is i dont know how to pass the right index to the v-tabs component from the check box...

i can not modify the array of Objects because it comes from a rest Api, this is just an example to simplify the issue. it would be great if i can use the item.index or item.name to make it work without modifing the array...

would be so thankfull if some one can help

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1. You don't have to put a `v-for` on a `<template>` element surrounding `<v-list-item>`. If you want multiple v-list-items, put the `v-for` on `<v-list-item>` instead.
2. Don't use `v-text` when normal [text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation) will do
3. `:key` can be given any unique string OR number.  If index is unique (and it's guaranteed to be) you don't need to create a string from it, just use "index".
4. Don't combine a `v-if` with a `v-for`.  Put the v-if on a wrapper/parent element if you can.

#4 is a tricky one to deal with sometimes, including in your situation here with `<v-tab>`.  You need the `v-for` to iterate and create multiple tabs, but you can't really put a `v-if` on a parent element because the parent is `<v-tabs>` and you don't want that conditionally rendered. You could maybe wrap the v-tab elements in another div or span, but that would intefere with vuetify's CSS, which you could maybe fix, but there is another option.

The other option: create a computed property that will return an array only containing tabs that should be displayed. This new computed property will be what we will loop with `v-for` to render our tabs and tab-items. Each original tab object in `tabs` will need a new boolean property that can tell us whether it should be displayed or not.  the `hidecont()` method you have will receive the index of the tab that should be hidden and toggle that boolean property.

Here's the updated code:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tabs v-model="activeTab">
      <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in computedTabs" :key="index">
        {{ item.name }}
      </v-tab>

      <v-tab-item v-for="(item, index) in computedTabs" :key="index">
        <v-card flat>
          {{ item.name }}
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
      <v-menu
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-width="200"
        offset-x
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <div class="d-flex align-center">
            <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
              <v-icon>mdi-eye</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedTabs" multiple>
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="index">
                <v-list-item-action class="ma-0">
                  <v-checkbox
                    :key="index"
                    @click="hidecont(index)"
                  ></v-checkbox>
                </v-list-item-action>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
    </v-tabs>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: 0,
      selectedTabs: [],
      menu: false,
      checked: false,
      tabs: [
        {
          name: "tab1",
          show: true,
        },
        {
          name: "tab2",
          show: true,
        },
        {
          name: "tab3",
          show: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    computedTabs() {
      return this.tabs.filter((t) => t.show === true);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    hidecont(index) {
      this.tabs[index].show = !this.tabs[index].show;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```